# SetDebugMessageDispatchHandler Error with node.js 0.6.6 on OpenSuse

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, opensuse

I'm getting the following errors when running `node` on `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)`

```
node --version
v0.6.6
node hello-console.js 
FATAL ERROR: v8::Debug::SetDebugMessageDispatchHandler Error initializing V8
```

I used the following commands to install it:

```
./configure --without-ssl --without-snapshot
make
make install
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By default V8 Tries to allocate 512 MB. You might want to adjust your address space using below:

```
ulimit -v unlimited
```

Otherwise, you would need to adjust `v8::internal::Heap::code_range_size` in the source.

This same problem can cause it not to complete compiling if you leave out `--without-snapshot` in the configure.